# Outlook Email Template With Input Box

Tags: outlook, user-input, outlook-2013

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

Firstly, I'm not even sure whether this is possible but I thought I'd ask.

I have a serious of Outlook Email templates which I want to adapt so that the operator can enter a recipients name, a user name and password.

Could someone tell me please whether this is possible and if so, how I would go about developing this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. But you can develop a VBA macro or COM add-in which can get the user's input and paste it to the email where required. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You may find the [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) article helpful.